# PHP echo different content every third week

Tags: php, date

I would like to echo out some text different text every third week, and can not figure out how. If it was every second week I could do it like this:

```
if(date("W") % 2 == 0)
    echo 'It is Joes turn';
else
    echo 'It is Marks turn';
```

But how to include a third turn and person and have this show correct turn every third week from a spesific date?

Googled and read multiple articles but have not found anything other than related to every second week.

Comment: `date("W") % 3` will return either 0, 1, or 2. So you can adjust your conditional based on that response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using modulo is the right approach.
You could combine it with a switch

```
switch (date("W") % 3) {
  case 1:
    echo "Week 1";
    break;
  case 2:
   echo "Week 2";
   break;
  case 0:
    echo "Week 3";
    break;
}
```

Consider switch a shorthand for 3 if/else statements, with the modulo being evaluated only once and internally passed as "invisible" variable.

Note: date("W") returns the ISO-8601 week number, and starts with one. Hence the first week is not "0".

Comment: Thank you. I should have achieved this without asking I now understand... :-)

Comment: @neppers: No worries. You just added another tool to your repertoire. :-)